# Trying to make activity button onclick trigger fragment button too Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to make a button from activity that when is clicked it will trigger click on fragment button too at the same time.

Don't bother anymore i solve it :)

Comment: I cannot see any question yet. What *exactly* is the problem? You might want to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I mean when i click the button from activity to trigger click on button from fragment too.., thx for your response btw, that was really fast

Comment: don't bother anymore i solve it :)